# How deploy apps in IbmCloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud

#### I can deploy my app in ibm cloud.

#### I made an organization. But when I enter the command

`ibmcloud target --cf` i see the following

```
API endpoint: https://cloud.ibm.com
Region: us-south
User: s.zababurin.v@gmail.com
Account: xArt (67d9c2412836032e4ceed1e621a97ffb)
Resource group: web3
CF API endpoint: https://api.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com (API version: 2.151.0)
Org:
Space:
```

#### There is no organization here.

I have the us-south region specified but the created organization has United Kingdom

When I execute the `ibmcloud cf push` command

I get an error

```
Invoking 'cf push' ...

No org targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG' to target an org.
FAILED
```

When I enter the command `ibmcloud cf target -o org`

I get

```
FAILED
Use 'ibmcloud target' to set or view target org or space.
```

When I enter `ibmcloud target -o org`

```
FAILED
Could not get org:
Organization 'org' was not found.

Organization established
```

### How can I specify the correct organization and space?

Comment: Do you have a lite account which only has one region enabled? Then you can only deploy there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command to check the `orgs` in a region

```
ibmcloud cf orgs
```

To set a region and also an `org` run the below command

```
ibmcloud target -r us-south -o xArt
```

> For region codes, run `ibmcloud regions`